# Calculation of interest on balance due

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have 3 tables Invoice, Payments and InterestRate. For purposes of simplicity I am representing each of the tables as follows.

The Invoice table has the following columns (the InvNum is the primary key)

```
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
    | InvNum       | InvDate     |  InvAmt       |
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
    |  123         |   2017-03-09|   15000       |
    |  456         |   2017-01-13|   20000       |
    +--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

The Payment table is as follows (the InvNum in the payments table is a foreign key which links to the Invoice table above

```
 +--------------+------------+----------+
    | payment_date | InvNum     |  amount  |
    +--------------+------------+----------+
    | 2017-08-10   |  123       |   5000   |
    | 2017-08-15   |  456       |   3000   |
    | 2017-09-15   |  123       |   3000   |
    | 2017-10-11   |  456       |   4000   |
    | 2017-10-16   |  123       |   3500   |
    | 2017-11-10   |  123       |   3000   |
    | 2017-11-15   |  456       |   2500   |
    +--------------+------------+----------+
```

My InterestRate looks something like this

```
    +--------------+-------+
    | ResetDate  |  IntRate|
    +--------------+--------+
    |  2016-01-01|   10     |
    |  2017-06-08|   10.25  |
    |  2017-11-03|   10.67  |
    |  2018-05-03|   10.83  |
    |  2018-07-29|   10.72  |
    |  2019-01-01|   10.67  |
    +------------+----------+
```

What I need is to calculate the interest for each Invoice after considering each payment and the final balance due on the invoice (in case it has not been fully paid).  The final table should look something like this

```
  InvNum    IntFrom    IntTo      Amount  IntRate  Interest  Payment  Balance
   123     2017-03-09 2017-06-07  15000   10         xxx      0        15000
   123     2017-06-08 2017-08-10  15000   10.25      yyy      5000     10000
   123     2017-08-11 2017-09-15  10000   10.25      zzz      3000      7000
   123     2017-09-16 2017-10-16  7000    10.25      aaa      3500      3500
   123     2017-10-17 2017-11-02  3500    10.67      bbb      0         3500
   123     2017-11-03 2017-11-15  3500    10.67      ccc      2500      1000
   123     2017-11-16 2018-05-02  1000    10.67      ddd      0         1000
   123     2018-05-03 2018-07-28  1000    10.83      eee      0         1000
   123     2018-07-29 2018-12-31  1000    10.72      fff      0         1000
   123     2019-01-01  (today)    1000    10.67      ggg      0         1000
```

I have not shown the results of Inv#456.  But the desired solution needs to group each of the invoices in the invoice table.

So in effect the interest calculation takes into account the payments made against each invoice (listed in the Payments table) as well as the changing interest rates (listed in the InterestRate table).  Of equal importance is the fact that the interest on the balance due on each invoice (1000 for inv#123) needs to calculated till the date of running the query.

One of the challenges I am also facing is how can I capture the above results in a table.  Would it mean dropping and recreating the table every time you run the query (since everytime the date changes the interest amount on the balance due will undergo a change).  So unless only the interest on the balance per invoice can be updated, it would (should?) necessarily mean that the table has to be dropped and re-created.  Alternatively, the results have to be viewed through a view query.

I hope I have been able to articulate my problem satisfactorily.

Thanks a lot for your time and attention to helping me out

Comment: 1. Do you calculate interest daily? 2. What is your interest posting period? Daily/Monthly? 3. You will need another table to store Invoice Interest calculations. Data will come from interest rate table as well as Invoice Balance.

Comment: Interest will be calculated weekly for every completed week (or part thereof).  The interest calculation will only be to determine the total liability on account of interest.  Therefore, the culmination of this exercise will be to determine the total amount to be settled against each invoice to completely discharge the liability on account of invoice balance as well as interest on overdue payment.

I note your response regarding another table for interest calculation.  However, I am unable to conceive the design of the query to fully address the solution I seek.

Comment: You say interest rate is calculated weekly: how would you handle interest rate change on Wednesday? Note: the logic you are trying to implement is non trivial (but not too complex), you need to be very clear about the business rules required, else you will have to rewrite your code a few times and I can't give you accurate suggestions.

Comment: If you are not certain yet, then I will give you general approach to implementing it.

Comment: Alex thanks for your reply. I apologise I couldn’t reply earlier as I was on vacation. Yes please any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I missed out to reply to a question posed by you. The interest for part of a week would be for a full week